# XMLType vs CLOB in oracle?

Tags: xmltype

Could anyone please explain me what are the 
differences between XMLType datatype and 
CLOB datatype,till now I was writing XML file
into physical path but now I wanted to change 
the way. After doing google I came to know the replication of varchar(Max) in oracle is CLOB.

Which one is better to use XMLtype or CLOB ?
please help